# Why R needs XQuartz, Xcode and Fortran?

Tags: r, xcode, macos, xquartz

I would like to start with R. I use macOS. And I saw on the website of R that they mention to install XQuartz, Xcode (or Command Line Tools) and Fortran before.
However, I wonder what these 3 things are good for in relation to R?
Do I really need them, so that R runs?
For what are they specifically used and what do they do?

Edit: At no point is it asked that I want a recommendation! It is asked what exactly the "things" do. To understand the functionality behind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These tools are recommended because they are *sometimes* useful (and it may be easier to install them up front rather than suddenly realizing you need them in the middle of a project). They are *not* required for basic use of R.

From the [R for MacOS web page](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/) [emphasis added]:

> **the use of X11 (including tcltk)** requires XQuartz

- `X11` is an older window management system that *some* packages use
- `tcltk` is an older tool that some packages use for presenting interactive buttons/widgets/etc.
- you might need this for the `rgl` package, which renders interactive 3D graphics

> **If you wish to compile R packages which contain Fortran code**, you may need to download the corresponding GNU Fortran compiler

Most R packages are available in a pre-compiled binary format, in which case you don't need XCode or gfortran. *If* you want to install development versions of packages (e.g. from someone's GitHub repository), *and* those packages contain compiled (C++ or Fortran) code, then you'll need XCode. Sometimes you'll see a message when installing packages about "binary available, but source is newer. Compile from source?". In this case it's usually safe to say "no".